# C# Update a Page from another Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have Page A and Page B

When Page A loads Page B loads too on background (its a service that I need to run).

Page A finishes loading and than Page B finishes loading.

When Page B finishes loading I would like to update a control on Page A

I've tried a few things with no success.

First one:
On Page B

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parceiros _p = new parceiros();
        _p.Update();
    }
```

Since the Page is already rendered it gives me Object reference not set of course (like the label does not exists) by the way, I've tried this before the  Page B unload too...

Second one:
When Page B finished loading, I've called a Javascript function from my code behind, and this javascript is suppose to do the job, it didn't work as well. I've even tried to call a alert() function but i doest not work. Since the Page that the user is, is Page A, it didn't work but i had to give it try.

Any one have any ideia how can I do this.

I though of Session as well but since page A finishes loading first I don't know how I could get the value...

Edited as required:

Here is the code I called on the Page_Unload on Page B

```
string jsGeral = "/js/geral.js";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(jsGeral, jsGeral);


        jsChart.Add(dataset);

        Page.RegisterStartupScript("myScript", "<script language=JavaScript>DoSomething();</script>");
        Response.Write(jsChart.ToString());
```

Comment: using java script function can be good idea, can we see what you did by java script?

Comment: @DeveloperX: **JavaScript**...

Comment: This sounds like an enormous hack and is for sure not the correct solution to your problem. The better question here would be to find a solution to your actual problem that apparently forces you to create such hacks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally what you can do:

**In page A:**

Load Page B

**In page B after loaded:**

Set a session variable

**In page A:**

Server Side: Define a function that returns new control content if the session variable is set.

Client Side: Periodically check for the new content by invoking that function in your page.